# Could any py file be called as a module?

Tags: python

Modules are python files. In reverse, does any python file could be treated as a module? What is the difference? Thanks.
print('hello world')

Comment: 1. A file with a name such as my-file.py cannot be imported but a file named my_file.py can. 2. The file has to be in a location listed in the `sys.path` list of strings providing search locations for modules and packages.

Comment: Could you tell how your example piece of code "print('Hello World'" illustrate the question ? If you have tried with some real code, please show it, so you can have a specific answer to your problem, if any ?

Answer (score -1):

Basically, yeah! For example, if I have a file called MyModule.py, and in it is a function that says `"Hello World"` I could access that function in another file in that same directory like:

```
from MyModule import MyFunction
```

As long as there are no conflicting names or anything like that, it should work fine.

Comment: Could you explain why you downvoted my answer?

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but it is essentially incorrect -- an oversimplification. Not every file can be imported, for example, my-file.py. You cannot say `import my-file`. And what is a "conflicting name"? Or what do you mean by "anything like that"?